# iOS: -webkit-overflow-scrolling causes nested fixed div to scroll

Tags: html, ios, css

On the iPhone, when using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` on a `position:fixed` element, a nested `position:fixed` element also scrolls with unexpected behavior. How can I prevent this?

https://output.jsbin.com/gugidecive

https://jsbin.com/gugidecive/edit